# How many times, and for how long has Orban had his legislation give him power to rule by decree since 2010?

Tags: legislation, executive-order, hungary, autocracy

I am looking for an answer with reliable sources to the specific dates between which such matters occurred.

I'm sure the best source would be digging up the Hungarian quasi-legislations minutes, but I am hoping to find English language sources.